# operator>> returns failure when I enter a 4-digit number after setting the locale

Tags: c++, macos, locale, c++14

I'm running into some really weird behaviour when I use `imbue` to set the
locale for `cin`.

```
// example.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
int main(){
# ifdef LOCALE
  std::cin.imbue(std::locale(LOCALE));
# endif
  long temp;
  const bool status = static_cast<bool>(std::cin >> temp);
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << status << " " << temp << std::endl;
}
```

I can compile and run this code without issue if I don't imbue the current
locale.

```
$ g++ example.cpp -o no-imbue -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror
$ echo 100 | no-imbue
true 100
$ echo 1001 | no-imbue
true 1001
```

However, if I imbue the current locale, `std::cin >> temp` starts failing for
four digit numbers:

```
$ g++ example.cpp -o imbue-empty -DLOCALE='""' -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror
$ echo 100 | imbue-empty
true 100
$ echo 1001 | imbue-empty
false 1001
```

Using `"en_US.UTF-8"` as the locale name instead of `""` seems to have the same
effect.

```
$ g++ example.cpp -o imbue-utf8 -DLOCALE='"en_US.UTF-8"' -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror
$ echo 100 | imbue-utf8
true 100
$ echo 1001 | imbue-utf8
false 1001
```

I'm on OSX using `clang-600.0.57`

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is this a bug with the compiler, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ninjaedit> Reproduced for `"en_US.UTF-8"` locale, however cannot be reproduced for the empty locale case (`Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)`).

Comment: It [looks like there were locale issues with that version of the compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2016-02/msg01518.html)

Comment: @dfri: Yeah, the empty case didn't reproduce when I ran it within a cram testfile, but did at the command line.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745045) as well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190072/), possibly the same/a related issue.

Comment: Looks like a [libc++/libstdc++ difference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86fe0dc79bbde2b2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you input `1,001`, your program should print `true`.

The `en_US` locale expects a comma between each group of three digits.  Because you didn't provide one, [`std::num_get::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) sets `failbit` on `std::cin`.  See the link for more detail, but the relevant excerpts are:

> ### Stage 2: character extraction
>
> If the character matches the thousands separator
>   (`std::use_facet<std::numpunct<charT>>(str.getloc()).thousands_sep()`)
>   and the thousands separation is in use at all
>   `std::use_facet<std::numpunct<charT>>(str.getloc()).grouping().length()
>   != 0`, then if the decimal point '.' has not yet been accumulated, the
>   position of the character is remembered, but the character is
>   otherwise ignored. If the decimal point has already been accumulated,
>   the character is discarded and Stage 2 terminates.

And

> ### Stage 3: conversion and storage
>
> After this, digit grouping is checked. if the position of any of the thousands separators discarded in Stage
>   2 does not match the grouping provided by
>   `std::use_facet<std::numpunct<charT>>(str.getloc()).grouping()`,
>   `std::ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`.

Comment: The wording here only covers *thousands separators discarded*, it doesn't state "or absent", making the use of the separators optional:

Comment: I can confirm that `echo 1,001 | imbue-utf8` outputs `true 1001`, so it looks this is it - the parser is requiring the thousands separator for this locale. Whether that behaviour is a bug or not is one for the forums.

Comment: The standard makes it clearer: (22.4.2.1.2/4) `Digit grouping is checked. That is, the positions of discarded separators is examined for consistency with use_facet<numpunct<charT> >(loc).grouping(). If they are not consistent then ios_-
base::failbit is assigned to err.`

Comment: That wording is still seems ambiguous, and it seems libstdc++ chose a different interpretation than libc++.  Just checked my Ubuntu box, and the thousands separator isn't needed there.

Comment: @kfsone so if nothing was discarded, there is nothing to check, right?